# failed to open sap gui for java in eclipse on M2 running macOS Sonoma 14.3

Tags: eclipse, macos, abap, abap-adt

I've created a program in abap that I want to run using eclipse instead of the gui, however I encounter following error message

```
Failed to open the SAP GUI for Java: No compatible installation of SAP GUI for Java was found. Minimum version is 074000000000. Required architecture is aarch64. Please install a compatible SAP GUI version.
```

[image: Message from eclipse]
What can I do to fix this? When trying to execute the program using sap gui everything works just fine.

I've tried downloading v7.8.0 of the sap gui as I've read that that version might help. However it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install correct SAP Java GUI version for MAC M2.
[image]

At the end your ABAP code will run in SAP GUI, Eclipse just trigger it.